# Flux that depends on a Mono resolution

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am learning about reactive programming and spring-webflux but I don't know how a Flux that depends on a Mono resolution should be returned.

```kotlin
interface FooRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Foo,String> {
    fun findAllByCreatedBy(email: String): Flux<Foo>
}

fun getCurrentUser() = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map { ctx -> ctx.authentication.principal }
            .cast(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java)
            .map(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::getPrincipal)
            .cast(User::class.java)
            .map(User::email)

 fun list(): Flux<ResponseEntity<Foo>> {
        val fooes = findAllByCreatedBy(getCurrentUser()) // This not work because getCurrenUser() returns a Mono<String>
        return fooes.map { o -> ResponseEntity(o, HttpStatus.OK)
 }
```

How can I wait or chaining getCurrentUser() output with findAllByCreatedBy()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For chaining *Mono* and *Flux* you can use [flatMapMany](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-) operator;

For example:

```
getCurrentUser()
 .flatMapMany(userEmail-> findAllByCreatedBy(userEmail))
```